# number of leap days in python with month and day

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, calendar

How to compute the number of leap days and make it ignore the leap year if the start date is after
Feb 29 or the end date is before Feb 29.

Here is my progress, sorry if it's messy. I'm new.

```
def compute_leap_years(start_year, start_month, start_day, end_year, end_month, end_day):
    if calendar.isleap(start_year) and (start_month >= 3 and not(bool(start_month == 2 and start_day == 29))):
        start_year = start_year + 1
    if calendar.isleap(end_year) and (end_month <= 2 and not(bool(end_month == 2 and end_day == 29))):
        end_year = end_year - 1
    days = calendar.leapdays(start_year, end_year)
    return days
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `calendar.leapdays()` but it looks like it excludes the final year.

If that's the case and assuming your input is all `int`s, this should work.

```python
import calendar

def compute_leap_years(start_year, start_month, start_day, end_year, end_month, end_day):
    # initialize your leapdays so you can keep a running count
    days = calendar.leapdays(start_year, end_year)
    # set yourself an end date as an int for easy comparison
    # here, end_day is zero padded to 2 characters to characterize
    # the dates as an increasing number from 101 to 1231
    end_date = int(f'{end_month}{end_day:02}')
    if calendar.isleap(start_year) and start_month >= 3:
        # if the start month is after february we know we have to subtract a day
        days -= 1
    if calendar.isleap(end_year) and end_date > 228:
        # and add a day if the excluded year is past the 28th and a leap year
        days += 1
    return days

# test cases
print(compute_leap_years(2016, 3, 2, 2020, 2, 28)) # 0
print(compute_leap_years(2016, 1, 2, 2020, 2, 28)) # 1
print(compute_leap_years(2016, 1, 2, 2020, 2, 29)) # 2
print(compute_leap_years(2020, 1, 2, 2020, 2, 28)) # 0
print(compute_leap_years(2020, 1, 2, 2020, 2, 29)) # 1
```

Keep in mind this does no checks for invalid date entry.

As an aside, there is almost never a reason to convert a comparison to `bool` as python has "truthy" values.